# Upload Binary Content with Tink Web

Tags: haxe

I want to upload an arrayBuffer from my javascript client, but i can't figure out how to define my Route

I tried the *@:consumes* metadata with **application/octet-stream** MimeType but the compiler doesn't like it.

```
class Api {

    public function new() { }

    @:post('/upload')
    @:consumes("application/octet-stream")
    public function upload(data:ArrayBuffer){
        trace(data);
    }

}
```

src/server/Api.hx:17: lines 17-19 : Warning : All defined routes are incomplete
src/server/Api.hx:15: characters 9-18 : Warning : Route does not capture argument`data`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that ArrayBuffer can't be created from the body stream? What if you changed it to just a https://api.haxe.org/haxe/io/Bytes.html?

Edit:
The docs (https://haxetink.github.io/tink_web/#/basics/parameters?id=advanced-data-types) mentions that parsers only exist for application/json and form-urlencoded mime types. an octet-stream parser doesn't exist (https://github.com/haxetink/tink_web/blob/master/src/tink/web/macros/MimeType.hx). you can probably write one, and parse the bytes into a Bytes object quite easily.